# How to Capture Image in Android?

Tags: android

I use the following code to capture the image.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAPT_PHOTO);
```

It work's fine for the HTC Legend,HTC desire,Samsung galaxy and Samsung galaxy tab.
But in LG optimus opens the camera and save the image file by it's own name and uri. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add an extra Extra: `MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE` where you can define the title of the  image. Hope this helps!

Comment: you mean instead of this line "cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri);" Shall i use this "cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE,outputFileUri);"

Answer (score 0):

```
   choosePhotoImage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/make_machine_example" + (counter++) + ".jpg";
                        File file = new File(choosePhotoImage);
                        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```